# How to declare 48-bit fixed-width data type in Java?

Tags: java, types

Is it possible to declare a fixed-width data type with maximum 48 bits in Java?
I need to find some method of storing 48 consecutive bits. I tried using a `Byte` array, but since it is a single continuous number it would need to be split up so I can't see how that would work as I need these values to be strictly fixed and not exceed 48-bit length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java there's no 48-bit data type. In fact the same thing happens on most modern platforms because they're mostly 8, 16, 32 or 64-bit systems. One way to overcome this is to declare it as a byte or short array.

```
byte db[size*6]; // or
short ds[size*3];
```

Each 48-byte element can be access by 6 consecutive bytes (3 consecutive shorts). The index of the array can easily be calculated from the 48-byte group index

```
long b[i] = db[i*6+0] << 40 | db[i*6+1] << 32 | db[i*6+2] << 24 |
            db[i*6+3] << 16 | db[i*6+4] <<  8 | db[i*6+5];
long c[i] = ds[i*3+0] << 32 | db[i*3+1] << 16 | db[i*3+2];
```

The 48-byte index can also be calculated from the byte/short array index. `db[i]` would be the `i % 6`<sup>th</sup> byte of the `i / 6`<sup>th</sup> 48-bit int.

or you can declare a class of bytes/shorts for more convenient access

```
class my6bytes {
    byte d[6];
}

my6bytes d6b[size];

class my3shorts {
    short s[3];
}

my3shorts d3s[size];
```

Comment: It's shameful that the OP hasn't bothered to check this as answered, because you have completely done so. Good, clear, straightforward answer which one can flexibly use for multiple solutions (including one for myself, so thanks!)

Comment: @BenjaminR I never realized this was answered in the first place. I might have missed the notifications, so I am sorry. I couldn't care less for the question anyway since it got answered 2 years after I had asked it. Completely forgot the context I asked that in, too.

Comment: @Setafire I know exactly how that happens. "Shameful" is probably a bit harsh of me, I just felt like if it's answered the OP has a responsibility to mark it as so. I feel like it clearly answers the text of the question, don't you?

Comment: @BenjaminR Yes it does.